# Docker error in Linux Mint

Tags: docker, linux-mint

I am trying to run a container in Docker, but i get allways the same error, for any container:

`sudo docker -D run -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g

2015/03/01 14:01:15 
[debug] stdcopy.go:112 framesize: 81
2015/03/01 14:05:48 finalize namespace drop capabilities operation not permitted
[debug] hijack.go:96 [hijack] End of stdout
[debug] commands.go:2004 End of CmdRun(), Waiting for hijack to finish.`

Andthe log file tells me nothing :-/

`2015/03/01 15:10:08 POST /v1.12/containers/create
[babaacd3] +job create()
[babaacd3] -job create() = OK (0)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 POST /v1.12/containers/cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1
[babaacd3] +job container_inspect(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job container_inspect(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] +job attach(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 POST /v1.12/containers/cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d/start
[babaacd3] +job start(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] +job allocate_interface(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job allocate_interface(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] +job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] +job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] +job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job allocate_port(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] -job start(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] +job release_interface(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 Stopping proxy on tcp/[::]:49161 for tcp/172.17.0.4:1521 (accept tcp [::]:49161: use of closed network connection)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 Stopping proxy on tcp/[::]:49160 for tcp/172.17.0.4:22 (accept tcp [::]:49160: use of closed network connection)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 Stopping proxy on tcp/[::]:49162 for tcp/172.17.0.4:8080 (accept tcp [::]:49162: use of closed network connection)
[babaacd3] -job release_interface(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
[babaacd3] -job attach(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)
2015/03/01 15:10:09 POST /v1.12/containers/cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d/wait
[babaacd3] +job wait(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d)
[babaacd3] -job wait(cb137c31e5e98ba97b1600c61aa91055bff4bb039800c0edbaf195be25b2519d) = OK (0)`

Kernel i am using:
Linux pc-desktop 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Does anyone knows what to do?

EDIT:
Here is another one trying to run Adrian Mouats suggestion:

user@user-desktop ~ $ sudo docker -D run debian echo Hello World

```
[debug] stdcopy.go:112 framesize: 38
2015/03/01 15:53:35 exec format error
[debug] hijack.go:96 [hijack] End of stdout
[debug] commands.go:2004 End of CmdRun(), Waiting for hijack to finish.
```

user@user-desktop ~ $ sudo service docker.io restart

```
docker.io stop/waiting
docker.io start/running, process 5467
```

user@user-desktop ~ $ sudo docker -D run debian echo Hello World

```
[debug] stdcopy.go:112 framesize: 81
2015/03/01 15:53:52 finalize namespace drop capabilities operation not permitted
[debug] hijack.go:96 [hijack] End of stdout
[debug] commands.go:2004 End of CmdRun(), Waiting for hijack to finish.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? I don't actually see any error messages...

Comment: There should be running an oracle database service as far as i know. Same command with echo hello world doesn't print me anything. Am i missing something?

Comment: I don't know. It's really hard to tell from this. What happens if you run: `docker run debian echo Hello World`

Comment: docker info gives me this: Containers: 46
Images: 65
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 157
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
WARNING: No swap limit support

Comment: Are you running on a 32bit host?

Comment: Looks like it - does `docker run 32bit/debian echo Hello World` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 32-bit host machine. Because of this, you won't be able to use the standard Docker images which are built for 64-bit Linux.

You might find that you can build your own images from Dockerfiles, but you won't be able to use the official images.

There are some images on the Hub which are built for 32bit architectures that you can try e.g: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/32bit/debian/

Answer (score 1):

I am using Linux mint 17.1. Installed docker.io as well as lxc-docker from docker's own site. It was somehow not starting up correctly quite like your case.

I had to install AppArmor for it to start correctly.

Use this set of instructions for 14.04:
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

Make sure you are running this: wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

That installs lxc-docker which is a high level wrapper around docker, allowing a number of additional dependencies to be correctly installed.

Issue regarding Ubuntu requirement on AppArmor:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9745